# Proper handling of two consecutive UserInterrupt in Haskell

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, exception

My program is running a quite long iterative IO computation. At each iteration, I'm saving an intermediary result in case of a shutdown request. Upon such a request I want to stop the computation and print the intermediary result before terminating the program. Here is what I achieved, it works, but when I press `CTRL-C` more than once in my terminal, the final print is not done. This is the first time I have to deal with asynchronous exceptions, so I may be wrong.

```
main :: String -> IO ()
main query = uninterruptibleMask $ \restore -> do
  results <- newIORef []
  xe      <- try $ restore $ search query results
  case xe of
    Right x -> printCompleted >> printResults x
    Left  e -> do
      printInterrupted
      readIORef results >>= printResults
      case e of
        UserInterrupt -> return ()
        _             -> throw e
```

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a pretty normal behavior for a program to have. The user hits `^C` once: okay, fine, you want me to quit, give me a minute and I'll print what I know so far. The user hits `^C` again while this is happening? They are tired of waiting for the program to quit, and want it to just get out of the way so they can run some other command.

Comment: @amalloy sure, but since `CTRL-C` (always?) sends `SIGINT`, I would expect this piece of code to *always* work since it's using `uninterruptibleMask`.

Comment: You are interruptible while printing, because you have called `restore` once `query` completes, no? I am not very familiar with async exceptions either, but from reading the Control.Exception docs it seems that the `restore` argument exists to allow you to restore the masking state so you can say you no longer need to be masked.

Comment: @amalloy I'm only calling `restore` inside `try` and the final print (`printInterrupted` and `printResults`) is done outside `try`.

Comment: So? `restore` [can be used to restore the prevailing masking state within the context of the masked computation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:mask). As far as I understand it, once your `try` completes successfully, the original masking state (i.e., not masked) will be restored, and so the rest of your `mask` computation is susceptible to being interrupted.

Comment: Really `uninterruptibleMask` seems very odd here, since you *do* want to allow the user to interrupt your long-running search operation. Why use any masking operation at all? Simply run `search query results` within a `try`, and you'll be able to detect whether it was interrupted. If you really want to guarantee printing, you can *at that point* turn on a mask to stop the printing code from being interrupted, although I don't think that is a great idea.

Comment: Apparently, the Haskell runtime kills the program on the second Ctrl-C by default, unless a signal handler is installed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349233/catching-control-c-exception-in-ghc-haskell

Comment: @danidiaz Thank you!

Comment: @amalloy I thought `restore` was only restoring the masking state for the computation taken as argument